# How to store multiple dates in a single column and use it as date?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-apex

I have a view that is used in a lot of reports. The view has DATE column that is the main parameter. But now I have to use a range of dates instead of the single date for all the reports; that is, the dates between two date columns.

For instance:
The View has these columns: COL1, DATE, DATE1, DATE2.
Reports are run (generally) like this:

```
SELECT col1, DATE FROM MY_VIEW WHERE DATE <= :PDATE;
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT col1, DATE FROM MY_VIEW WHERE [dates between DATE1 and DATE2] <= :PDATE;
```

So I need a view that has a column which stores the dates between DATE1 and DATE2 and rows return from the query when :PDATE is equal or less than any of the dates in the range without changing the query.

Comment: Is DATE2 guaranteed to be greater than DATE1?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: yes DATE2 is always greater than DATE1. Simply put, I want the range of dates between DATE1 and DATE2 to be used as a single date column that can be used as the mentioned query without changing it (the query)

Comment: OUTER JOIN a calendar table, JOIN ON date between DATE1 and DATE2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the WHERE condition, first check if the date is between Date1 and date2 and the check if they asre lower.

Only when both conditions are true you get a row returned.

```
SELECT col1, DATE FROM MY_VIEW 
WHERE DATE between DATE1 and DATE2 
AND DATE <= :PDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a list of dates in the range:

test data:

```
create table t (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint t_id_pk primary key,
    date1                          date,
    date2                          date
)
;

-- load data
 
insert into t ( date1, date2 ) values ( sysdate - 1, sysdate - 8 );
insert into t ( date1, date2 ) values ( sysdate + 1, sysdate - 2 );

select * from t;


        ID DATE1       DATE2      
---------- ----------- -----------
         1 03-OCT-2023 26-SEP-2023
         2 05-OCT-2023 02-OCT-2023

select t.id
      ,d.dt
  from t
 cross join lateral ( select date2 + level - 1 as dt
                                            from dual
                     connect by
                        level < t.date1 - t.date2 + 2
                     ) d

        ID DT         
---------- -----------
         1 26-SEP-2023
         1 27-SEP-2023
         1 28-SEP-2023
         1 29-SEP-2023
         1 30-SEP-2023
         1 01-OCT-2023
         1 02-OCT-2023
         1 03-OCT-2023
         2 02-OCT-2023
         2 03-OCT-2023
         2 04-OCT-2023
         2 05-OCT-2023
```

This select includes both lower and upper boundary dates. Change the `t.date2 + 2` to `t.date2 + 1` in the connect by clause to exlude the upper boundary date.

Comment: but this create extra rows. I need to return exactly one row if the parameter matches between the date range

Comment: Yeah... your question isn't very clear, I assumed this is what you wanted. If you want help, then create some sample data and clearly show what output you're expecting.  Add this to your question. What you are asking doesn't exist - at least not in the way you're suggesting it. But I'm 100% sure your business question can be answered. So... [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pls.

Answer (score 0):

You say that And DATE2 is always greater than DATE1. So, there is a range of dates defined from DATE1 to DATE2. For comparisons with another date it suffices to compare DATE1 or DATE2, depending on the comparison, and the other dates will meet the same criteria:

### All dates in the range must to be less or equal to :PDATE.

```
WHERE DATE2 <= :PDATE
```

### At least one date in the range must to be less or equal to :PDATE.

```
WHERE DATE1 <= :PDATE
```

### All dates in the range must to be greater or equal to :PDATE.

```
WHERE DATE1 >= :PDATE
```

### At least one date in the range must to be greater or equal to :PDATE.

```
WHERE DATE2 >= :PDATE
```

Comment: It may also be handled with `greatest/least` functions like `>= all` => `>= greatest(date1,date2)`, `>= any` => `>= least(date1,date2)`. Or `any`/`all` keyword if those dates arrive as different rows of subquery